# perl function call with arguments

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have written a function to execute a command on a remote machine.

```
Command : iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225 $okey $ikey
```

`$okey $ikey` values are passed as  arguments.

Now ,Sometimes I want to execute the command WITHOUT $okey and $ikey values.

```
Command : iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225
```

Now my question is ,How do i pass the $okey and $ikey values as optional arguments. If $okey and $ ikey values are NOT passed then the below command must be executed.

```
iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225
```

If $okey and $ ikey values are passed then the following command must be executed.

```
iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225 $okey $ikey
```

Function :

```
 sub gre_testing {
        my ($self,$okey,$ikey)  = @_;
        $self->execute('iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225 $okey $ikey'); 
        return 1;
 }
```

Function call :

```
gre_testing(1000,1000);
```

Comment: Single quotes don't interpolate variables. Use double quotes.

Comment: `my ($self, $okey, $ikey)  = (@_, ("") x 3-@_);`

Comment: @Сухой27 That's a little confusing to read. For me at least :|

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes, that's why I didn't write it as answer. Your approach is simpler and better.

Answer (score 4):

If you want them to be optional you need to actually write support for that in your `gre_testing` subroutine:

```
sub gre_testing {
    my ($self, $okey, $ikey)  = @_;

    # if these arguments are not passed
    # use the empty string so no value is interpolated below
    $okey //= ''; 
    $ikey //= ''; 

    $self->execute(
       "iptunnel add obs mode gre remote x.x.x.x local X.X.X.X ttl 225 $okey $ikey"
    ); 
    return 1;
}
```

Another issue is that the string you are passing to execute is quoted with single quotes, so none of your variables will be interpolated. Use double-quotes.

Now in the case that you don't want `$okey` and `$ikey` you simply say:

```
$self->gre_testing();
```

I noticed you defined `$self` above, but did not invoke your method on an object. I imagine you want to do this otherwise you will get an error when you try to `$self->execute(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Assign them the empty string if they're not set:

```
unless (defined $okey  &&  defined $ikey)
{
    $okey = $ikey = "";
}
```

Also, as `choroba` pointed out, you need double quotes in your `execute` call, not single quotes.